# How to correct extract string from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have A XML string like this:

```
<result>
     <id>1032</id>
     <name>SOME NAME</name>
     <price>25000</price>
     <img>http://somesite/some/some.png</img>
     <detail_text>DESCRIPTION</detail_text>
</result>
```

After parsing I get NSDictionary object like this:

```
result =     {
        "detail_text" =         {
            text = DESCRIPTION";
        };
        id =         {
            text = 1032;
        };
        img =         {
            text = "http://somesite/some/some.png";
        };
        name =         {
            text = "SOME NAME";
        };
        price =         {
            text = 25000;
        };
    };
}
```

And I want to have access to NSDictionary elements and save then like a string. When it was many elements ( image1   image2  ...) I using this:

```
_PtitleArr =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[_PxmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
```

And all works, but now only one element in it, and this way doesn't work any more. I'm trying do this: `_PtitleArr =[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[_PxmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"];`
Or so: `NSString *title = [[_PxmlDictionary objectAtIndex:0` (or "1")`] objectForKey:@"name"];` But always xCode give me an error:

```
-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8995070
2013-11-15 08:16:41.276 Akc_ver_0.1[8670:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8995070'
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I extract elements correctly?

Comment: I have updated please try like that and check??

Comment: The above code will not return the above error.  Somewhere you're calling `count` on a string.  Did you mean to use `length`?

Comment: It looks like the dictionary you are getting is much more complicated than it needs to be for the XML you are using.  Chances are there is something going a little wrong with your parser.  I learned how to parse XML from [this video series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tUxV_66Q4U&feature=related).  It's about 30 minutes long in total, but probably well worth the time.  I would suggest trying to follow through that, it should work nicely for the XML you posted, and it should be easy to figure out how to get the strings out in the end.

Comment: Yep, the XML parser is inserting a second dictionary with a "text" key for each element value.  One would hope that there's a parser option to suppress this and give you, eg, `id = 1032` vs `id = {...`.

Comment: NSDictionary looks as if you are using XMLReader. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml format looks like it contains dictionary inside dictionary. So try to access like that below

```
 NSDictionary * dict=[_PxmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] ;
```

Now try to fetch the dictionary value in NSString

```
  NSDictionary *dict1=[dict objectForKey:@"name"];

 NSString *str=[dict1 objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: `name` is dictionary. correct: `NSString *str=[[dict objectForKey:name] objectForKey:@"text"];

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko It says me: Use of undeclared identifier "name"

Comment: @hussainShabbir thanks, it's strange - I'm trying do that before but then it returned me null

Comment: I have break into dictionary check still it is showing null??